# Is it possible to externally authenticate in Tomcat using OAuth?

Tags: java, tomcat, authentication, oauth

In tomcat, I can setup security constraints that require certain resources to only be accessed by authorized users. The users are authenticated using either BASIC or FORM authentication, where a username and password is provided.

However, I'd also like to allow users to authenticate externally using an oauth provider. Is this possible?

Note that I can already pass all the information I need to acquire the access tokens for the user.  From there I can get the username and other profile metadata.

But how do I then log the user into tomcat? The only way I can think to make this work is to take this username and create a tomcat account, maybe setting the access token as the password.  Then I could do a tomcat login on behalf of the user, so she is locally authenticated.  On subsequent logins I'd just update the password to the new access token.

But this seems like a hack, and when it comes to users and security I'd prefer to avoid hacks.

It looks like JASPIC might offer a solution for this?  Unfortunately, it looks like it became available to tomcat starting at 8.5 but I'm stuck using 8.

Are there any other options?

Thanks!

Comment: The Tomcat-specific extension points you're after are [Authenticator](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/valve.html#Authentication) (for protocol-level processing) and (potentially) [Realm](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/realm-howto.html) (for protocol-neutral credential validation). But, like JASPIC, these merely provide container-managed authentication integration. Everything besides that you will have to worry about yourself (likely assisted by some third-party library).